# Split Image in Pygame

Tags: python, image, split, pygame, blit

I have a 200x200px image in pygame that I'd like to slice in half, so the 2 shapes would be 100x200px.  Afterwards, I'd like to blit the 2 new images on the screen with a set amount of pixels in between them.  How would an image be split/cropped in such a way?

EDIT - Fixed!  I managed to figure this out by myself from using `pygame.transform.chop()` and `pygame.transform.rotate()`.  Thanks for the help, though.  I know a little more thanks to the help of Tankor Smash.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to create two images, just use one and blit it twice:

```
origin1 = (0,0)
separation = 20

# Load the image
img = pygame.image.load(image_path)

width, height = img.get_width()/2, img.get_height()
origin2 = origin1[0] + width + separation, origin1[1]

# Blit first half
source_area = pygame.Rect((0,0), (width, height))
screen.blit(img, origin1, source_area)

# Blit second half
source_area = pygame.Rect((width,0), (width, height))
screen.blit(img, origin2, source_area)
```

Comment: For some reason the blit destination is outside the screen, despite setting it to 4000x4000.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/test.py", line 24, in <module>
    screen.blit(img, origin2, source_area)
TypeError: invalid destination position for blit

Comment: @Alpha15, I did a minor edit, perhaps that was the problem, origin2 was missing the second coordinate: ´origin2 = origin1[0] + width + separation, origin1[1]´

Comment: @pmoleri I edited the question saying I figured it out.  Thanks for offering your help though.  :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'd be better using `PIL`, here http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/

But if you were to use Pygame, it'd be something along the lines of creating a surface with the image on it, then blitting one half of the surface to a part of the screen, then the other half at another.

```
#load the image to a surface
img =pygame.image.load(path) 
#create a rect half the width of the image
half_rect = pygame.rect(img.width/2, img.height/2)
#blit first half
main_screen.blit((0,0), rect, img)
#blit second half
main_screen.blit((image.width+10,0),rect, img)
```

Now that's pseudocode, but that's how I'd do it, roughly

Comment: Apparently there is no width attribute.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/test.py", line 11, in <module>
    half_rect = pygame.Rect(img.width/2, img.height/2)
AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'width'

Comment: You'd have to do some learning but I would think that the full code was `img.get_rect().width`. Look up the search terms, Pygame Rect and Pygame surface for more info. It's all strange at first, it get gets fairly simple.

Answer (score 0):

The other method is to use `subsurface`s http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#Surface.subsurface

If you have many sprites on one sheet, you can use it as a spritesheet : http://www.pygame.org/wiki/Spritesheet?parent=CookBook